# Extracting a function from set of inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, inequality

I have set of inequalities in two dimension space which represent relation between $X$ and $Y$. Now I want a function whose input is $X$ and output is $Y$. In other words, I want $F$ such that $F(X)=Y$ satisfying given inequalities.

For example
$$ X \le 0,~ Y\ge0,~ X\le63,~ Y\le15, ~X\ge4Y,~ X\le4Y+3$$

Now in above case if I input X, function should return Y. Hence, for example, in above case $F(0)=0$ and $F(4)=1$ and so on...

You can plot these function on WolframAlpha and see how it gives integer solutions. But I'm looking for a function which maps X to Y.

Is it possible to get such function?

Comment: Do you want any function with graph in that area? Surely you must see that $F(4)$ could be anywhere in $[0.25, 1]$ and still satisfy the inequalities.

Comment: Ok..even if function returns anything in some range, I can take ceil value of it..basically I want both X and Y to be integers..on WolframAlpha page have a look at Integer solutions section..

Comment: So you want integers that satisfy the inequality? You should really say so. In general this has nothing to do with functions. In this case, just take $F(x) = \lfloor x/4 \rfloor$.

Comment: Yes I figured out that but is there any library that can do it for me?

Comment: Library? Are you talking about programming? Most languages have a floor() in their standard libraries...

Comment: @Karolis I think you forgot question..Given set of inequalities, is there any library that can return such function:

Comment: No, there is no such library because usually integer solutions of a set of inequalities cannot be written as a function. If you have some extra constraints on the inequalities, you should name them.